# How to get javascript generated title tooltip for SVG to show up

Tags: javascript, svg, tooltip

I'm trying to get a tooltip for an SVG element.  (Testing under Firefox 16.0.2) I tried this little example and it works fine:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect id="test" x="20" y="30" width="200" height="150">
  <title>Test tooltip</title>
  </rect>
</svg>
```

But, I need to generate the tooltip from javascript, as the SVG is also being generated from javascript.  So just as a first test, I tried generating just the tooltip:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function test(text) {
  var title = document.createElement("title")
  title.text = text
  document.getElementById("test").appendChild(title)
}

</script>
</head>

<body onload="test('Test tooltip')">

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect id="test" x="20" y="30" width="200" height="150">
  </rect>
</svg>
```

When I inspect the results from Firefox the title objects appears identical to the title generated from the HTML/SVG, except that **when I mouse over the rectangle there is no tooltip**!  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The title element should be in the SVG namespace, not the default namespace. Therefore, you should use `createElementNS()`. Also, the SVG title element does not have the `text` property. Use `textContent` instead. So, this should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function test(text) {
  var title = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","title")
  title.textContent = text
  document.getElementById("test").appendChild(title)
}

</script>
</head>

<body onload="test('Test tooltip')">

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect id="test" x="20" y="30" width="200" height="150">
  </rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: @codenamezero You mean like `<use><title></title></use>`, or do you mean a title in an element referenced by use? In both cases: Just try it and feel free to report back about your findings.

Comment: Yeah, `<use><title></title></use>` is that the right way to do it because I am not getting the title to show up?

Comment: @AnkurMarwaha Of course. Just put the title element inside whatever element you want the tooltip for.